# What does this code mean in GCC?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, memory-management, malloc

I am tracing my way through what `malloc()` does in GCC.

I started with the public malloc `void* __libc_malloc(size_t bytes)` function, which calls `arena_lookup()`, found in `arena.c`:

```
void* __libc_malloc(size_t bytes)
{
  mstate ar_ptr;
  void *victim;
  void *(*hook) (size_t, const void *) = force_reg (__malloc_hook);
  if (__builtin_expect (hook != NULL, 0))
    return (*hook)(bytes, RETURN_ADDRESS (0));

  arena_lookup(ar_ptr);
  .
  .
}
```

Below is the function `arena_lookup()` and I insert the definition of each function which is called (the dashed lines contain each level of function definition):

```
#define arena_lookup(ptr) do { \
    void *vptr = NULL; \
    ptr = (mstate)tsd_getspecific(arena_key, vptr); \

//tsd_getspecific-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #define tsd_getspecific(key, vptr)  ((vptr) = __libc_tsd_get (void *, MALLOC))

//__libc_tsd_get-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        #define __libc_tsd_get(TYPE, KEY) \
        (*__libc_tsd_address (TYPE, KEY))

//__libc_tsd_address-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            #define __libc_tsd_address(TYPE, KEY)       (&__libc_tsd_##KEY)
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
} while(0)
```

I end up in `libc-tsd.h` with `__libc_tsd_address(TYPE, KEY)` defining `(&__libc_tsd_##KEY)`, but **I do not understand what this code means?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *token pasting* or token concatenation, described [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html). It concatenates preprocessor tokens to create a new token to be processed by the C compiler. If it's called as

```
__libc_tsd_address(void *, MALLOC)
```

it expands to:

```
&__libc_tsd_MALLOC
```

Or if `MALLOC` is also a defined macro, its expansion will be substituted there.

Comment: I kind of understand what you are saying. Could you give some details at a level slightly higher. So its effectively creating code to be called?

Comment: It's creating a reference to a variable name that combines the two words.